# jquery autocomplete call function if only 1 record returned

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am wanting to run a function of the jQuery autocomplete below only returns 1 result. I am not sure how to check that there is only 1 result in the list.

Please help.

```
$(function() {

  function log(message) {

    $("<div>").text(message).prependTo("#log");

    $("#log").scrollTop(0);

  }

  $("#inputBox2").autocomplete({

    source: "searchsalonproduct.php",

    cacheLength: 0,

    minLength: 1,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      addcharge(ui.item.id);

      return false;

    }

  }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li></li>")
      .data("item.autocomplete", item)
      .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
      .appendTo(ul);
  };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the response event to check. The results found are stored in ui.content (ui is an argument in the event handler).

```js
$("#inputBox2").autocomplete({

  source: "searchsalonproduct.php",

  cacheLength: 0,

  minLength: 1,
  select: function(event, ui) {
    addcharge(ui.item.id);

    return false;

  },
  response: function(event, ui) {
    
    if(ui.content.length === 1) {
      //do stuff
    }
  }

}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
  return $("<li></li>")
    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
    .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
    .appendTo(ul);
};
```